# Roll the dice program winner in a cron job

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I want to run a PHP script in a cron job. My host limits me a lot, I have to wait hourly in order for the cron job to repeat.

I have a 120s timer that is decremented using javascript and updated as it hits 0 to prevent desynchronization.

I'd like to do some sort of "roll the dice" program where everyone that joins in will enter some sort of lobby array, that lobby array should be iterated to my cron job php script and pick a winner there.

I want to implement this [structure](https://hastebin.com/jahutayube.xml) in the cronjob.

---

How I am calculating the timer:

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();
$nextTwoMinute = ceil($timestamp/120) * 120;
echo json_encode(($nextTwoMinute - $timestamp));    
?>
```

How I am decrementing with JS:

```
var add_secs = " s";
var time_s = setInterval(update_time, 1000);

function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
var currTime = "";
 //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {
    currTime = this.responseText;
};
window.onload = function() {
    //dom not only ready, but everything is loaded
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("get", "scripts/php/calc.inc.php", true);
    oReq.send();
};
function update_time() {
    document.getElementById("time_left").value = currTime<0 ? currTime=117:currTime--;
    $("input.circle").val(currTime);
    $("input.circle").trigger('change');
}
```

I found a solution to my problem without the use of cron job:

```
$key=md5('ILOVEYOU');
    $serverseed = floor(time() / 5);
    srand($serverseed);
    $result = rand();

    $modulus_result= $result % 100;
```

if anyone is interested in the solution: this generates a random integer for 5 seconds!

Comment: what is it, exactly, that you are asking?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying! I want to know how I could possibly keep that php file active on my cronjob which is limited to only execute hourly.

Comment: How do you access the cron job manager? through a cpanel?

Comment: I don't have access to the console, they only let me set the php path for the file to execute

Comment: Wow. I do hope that's a free service, if not, change this very moment. Even the crappiest of shared webhost will get you a cpanel, from which you can manage cron jobs and set them every minute if you wish

Comment: it's not xD but it's pretty cheap!

Comment: Anyways, I ended up finding a far easier solution:

Comment: $key=md5('ILOVEYOU');
 $serverseed = floor(time() / 5);
 srand($serverseed);
 $result = rand();

 $modulus_result= $result % 100;

Comment: Please post your solution as an **answer**, after a time period you will be able to accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem:

```
   <?php  
    $key=md5('ILOVEYOU');
    $serverseed = floor(time() / 5);
    srand($serverseed);
    $result = rand();

    $modulus_result= $result % 100;

    echo "before: ".$modulus_result."<br>";
    echo "after: ".encrypt($modulus_result, $key)."<br>";
    echo decrypt($modulus_result, $key);

    function decrypt($string, $key){
        $string = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
        return $string;
    }   
    function encrypt($string, $key){
        $string = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
        return $string;
    }   

?>
```

by using time() you can seed the rounded quotient of the time() by nº secs you want the rand number to be active then use modulus to limit the range. there will be a random number for a period of time and it'll always be the same as it uses time() as a reference.

I hope this helps some people.
You can even encrypt this data for cross-platform transfers.